# when use lots of \color{} command, can't change color

Tags: xetex, color

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue

from here, something is wrong?

\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue
\color{red}red  \color{green}green  \color{blue}blue

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong and I can run that code without problems.

Comment: I don't see any problems

Comment: but on my computer,  all words after "from here, something is wrong?" are red?

Comment: My counting may be off, but is that happening after 128 color changes?  That close to 2^7 seems suspicious.  What OS do you have?  What version of xcolor?

Comment: Please, tell us whether you're using XeLaTeX or PDFLaTeX as engine.

Comment: Indeed XeLaTeX is broken

Comment: yes, 127 is right, from 128 is wrong. Ubuntu 16.04.1  / texlive 2014 / XeLaTeX  engine / xcolor 2.11. can i change the 128 directly :-)

Comment: I guess this is a limitation of the `xdvipdfmx` driver that cannot handle more than 128 groups. Each `\color` command does a `color push`.

Comment: Color changes should not be handled that way, but with groups.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: does it work with lualatex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I run this code with

```
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" zeno
```

I get on the console

```
<FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>No dvi filename specified, reading standard input.
stdin -> zenorig.pdf
DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2018.04.17:1712
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf@9.96pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf".
(CID:LMRoman10-Regular)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf/0/H/65536/0/0,0>.
>
xdvipdfmx:warning: Color stack overflow. Just ignore.
xdvipdfmx:warning: Color stack overflow. Just ignore.
xdvipdfmx:warning: Color stack overflow. Just ignore.
[...several other similar lines...]
xdvipdfmx:warning: Color stack overflow. Just ignore.
xdvipdfmx:warning: Color stack overflow. Just ignore.
]
otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf"...
(CID:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf[IXRNFR+LMRoman10-Regular][CIDFontType0][20 glyphs][2804 bytes])
Compression saved 14964 bytes
5364 bytes written
```

Each `\color` command executes

```
\special {color push \current@color }\aftergroup \reset@color
```

but the `push` is never followed by a `pop` (except at the end of the job).

The color stack apparently has a limitation of 127 or 128 positions (you get red, I get blue, so it can be off by one depending on the version of the software).

Use `{\color{<color>}text}` or, better,

```
\textcolor{<color>}{text}
```

for color changes.

Comment: Just to provide some relevant info: noted `dvipdfm-x`'s source file [`pdfcolor.c@r55807`](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/dvipdfm-x/pdfcolor.c?revision=55807&view=markup) has `#define DEV_COLOR_STACK_MAX 128` and `if (color_stack.current >= DEV_COLOR_STACK_MAX-1) { WARN("Color stack overflow. Just ignore."); } else { ... }`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Maybe there is more in this than just the definition of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this with a beamer with >32 references.

Since each `\bibitem` will fire 4 color commands, the 31th breaks.

To fix this, I added additional grouping by

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry author}{\bgroup}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{\egroup}
```

If that gives you a `missing } before \end{bibliography}` error, try

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry author}{\bgroup}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{\egroup}
```

instead.